# WPF app - Model object placement / project structure (in a MVVM scenario)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, model, data-modeling, models

I'm developing a WPF click once application using Prism v4, and MEF (MVVM pattern). I have multiple modules that reside in their own assemblies.

I'm trying to figure out where to place my model objects.

Would you place them in the assembly where they're primarily used (even though they could be used in other assemblies), or would you create an assembly to house all of the models (to be more easily used in other programs)? I'm leaning towards the latter but that brings be to the next question below...

How would you go about distinctly separating model objects, who are populated from different databases / servers - do you clump them all together in the same assembly / namespace or separate them into different namespaces / assemblies? I'm trying to prevent issues down the road due to a bad decision starting this project and would appreciate anyones feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put the model objects in their own assembly.  This promotes reuse as well as separation, as its much more difficult to "pollute" the model with presentation related code.

As for your second question:

> How would you go about distinctly separating model objects, who are populated from different databases / servers - do you clump them all together in the same assembly / namespace or separate them into different namespaces / assemblies?

If you're planning to have models that are populated from multiple sources, I would personally put the Model definitions in one assembly, then use a DAL (in separate assemblies) per data source.  This keeps the model definitions separate from the data access, which in turn is still presentation-neutral.

If the Model will always be populated from a single data source, then keeping this together (but separating via namespaces) is probably a simpler option.